# Why can't I use ?: operators in the 3rd argument of for loops in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop

Why is the following code giving me an error?

```java
int n = 30000; // Some number
for (int i = 0;
     0 <= n ? (i < n) : (i > n);
     0 <= n ? (i++) : (i--)) { // ## Error "not a statement" ##
    f(i,n);
}
```

Comment: Why use the Ternary operator there? .... it so full of clutter. I know what you're going for but it just hurts....

Comment: I agree it's a little hard to read.

Comment: One quite interesting thing is that if you declare `int x = 0;` earlier in your code, you can use `x = (0 <= n ? (i++) : (i--))` and it will work.

Comment: A word of advice when asking questions like this in the future: "Why" questions are vague. "Why does the code give an error?" Because it is illegal. "Why is it illegal?" Because the specification says it is illegal. "Why does the specification say that?" Because that's what the language design team wrote. "Why did they write that?"  You'll have to ask them!  Compare that with a "what" question: "what section of the specification describes legal and illegal expressions in a for statement?" is a question that *has an answer*.

Comment: The ternary conditional isn't a statement by itself to begin with.

Comment: Because it's an expression and not a statement?

Comment: @EricLippert: Thats a bit like answering "Do you know what time it is?" with "Yes". Of course this is a programming site, and here are a lot of "technical types", but it doesn't mean we shouldn't expect a minimum of social skills from users.... The OP could have asked preciesely for a quote from the spec. But imagine there was a Java engineer here who knew *why* they decided to only allow statements there. Should s/he quote mechanically from the spec, or rather explain the rationale? There is value in being vauge, because the answerer knows more than the asker, and you might miss a good answer

Comment: @jdm: My point is that when a user asks "why does this give an error?" I don't know whether they're asking "is the compiler correct to mark this as an error?" or "what was the design rationale of this part of the language?" A "why" question is *vague* because it is not at all clear what answer would satisfy the questioner.

Comment: @EricLippert I think it was pretty clear from the question that the OP is wondering why Java outlaws this. A question, BTW, that nobody has answered so far...

Comment: @fgp: Since the accepted answer is "because the specification says so", I submit to you that your conclusion is not at all clear. I wonder also if you did not read my answer, which does give an explanation from a language design perspective.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's because the `for` loop has been defined that way in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html).

[14.14.1 The basic for statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1)

```
BasicForStatement:
    for ( ForInit ; Expression ; ForUpdate ) Statement

ForStatementNoShortIf:
    for ( ForInit ; Expression ; ForUpdate ) StatementNoShortIf

ForInit:
    StatementExpressionList
    LocalVariableDeclaration

ForUpdate:
    StatementExpressionList


StatementExpressionList:
    StatementExpression
    StatementExpressionList , StatementExpression
```

So it needs to be a `StatementExpression` or multiple `StatementExpression`s, and `StatementExpression` is defined as:

[14.8 Expression statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8)

```
StatementExpression:
    Assignment
    PreIncrementExpression
    PreDecrementExpression
    PostIncrementExpression
    PostDecrementExpression
    MethodInvocation
    ClassInstanceCreationExpression
```

`0 <= n ? (i++) : (i--)` is none of those, so it is not accepted. `i += ((0 <= n) ? 1 : -1)` is an assignment, so it works.

Comment: I appreciate that someone took time to quote the spec. But do you know *why* it is this way? This is not *why*, this is *how*. Its like saying: "It raises an error because it is implemented that way in the source."

Comment: @jdm I do think this is the *why*, but you're correct in that the next question would probably be why would it be defined this way. I think that was pretty much already answered by [Eric](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22579331/365237) though.

Comment: I was so glad to see a response to this question by showing the grammar of the language specification. There is hope left in this world. Thank you for restoring my faith in humanity, @eis.

Answer (score 23):

First of all, I would recommend against writing the code this way.  The purpose of the code is "count up from zero to n if n is positive, count down from 0 to n if n is negative", but I would be inclined to instead write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < abs(n); i += 1)
{
    int argument = n < 0 ? -i : i;
    f(argument, n);
}
```

But that does not answer your question, which is:

> Why can't I use `?:` operators in the 3rd argument of for loops in Java?

A `for` loop has the structure `for ( initialization ; condition ; action )`.

The purpose of an *expression* is to compute a value.

The purpose of a *statement* is to take an action.

There are some expressions which by design both compute a value and take an action.  `i++`, `i += j`, `new foo()`, `method()` and so on.

It is bad style to have any other expression that both computes a value and takes an action. Such expressions are difficult to reason about.

Therefore the action of the `for` loop is restricted to be *only those expressions which by design both compute a value and take an action*.

Basically, by forbidding this code the compiler is telling you that you've made a bad stylistic choice. `b?i++:i--` is a legal expression but it is really bad style because it makes what is supposed to be *computing a value* into *producing a side effect and ignoring the value*.

Comment: The way you'd be inclined to write is a bad coding practice; you've two invariants which are processed with each loop iteration, namely abs(n) and n < 0; besides, you don't have to use a temporary in this case, inlining the argument to "f( n < 0 ? -i : i; n)" wouldn't hurt at all here. If f() is a fast method and n is high enough, you'd be hurting the efficiency seriously.

Comment: (not to mention the ugly i += 1 you used... what's wrong with i++ nowadays?)

Comment: @vaxquis: First off, you apparently have the common but strange belief that eliminating the name associated with a temporary value somehow makes it "better". I am not sure where this strange belief comes from. Is this belief justified by evidence, or are you just asserting it?

Comment: @vaxquis: Second, I am unconcerned about the few extra nanoseconds incurred by the unnecessary computations in the loop. A good optimizer will detect the loop invariants and hoist them out. But more generally: it is a bad practice to nano-optimize a program without profile-directed evidence. Manually hoisting loop invariants in C# can actually cause the jitter to generate *slower* code. You should write code to be maximally clear, and then verify that it meets your performance goals.

Comment: First, it is not guaranteed by any means that the compiler or VM will inline it (because it *doesn't* have to; see -O0 switch in GCC for example) - and in case it doesn't, the variable has to get memory allocated for it (once) and get set (for each loop iteration); secondly, even if it *gets* inlined, it makes the code longer and less readable, making it longer by 50%. Should I post references supporting both claims or is that not particularly necessary?

Comment: @vaxquis: Third, the increment and decrement operators are frequently abused, as illustrated by this very question. I avoid them whenever possible, and it is *always* possible.

Comment: I see. And I assume you assume that HotSpot/JVM makes inlining a O(1) operation, that the compiler will *always* know if the value is invariant or no, and the fact that small loops iterating *millions* of times should be optimised? And the entire CS world is wrong for using "i++"/"i--" when it should be using more correct and clean "i+=1"/"i-=1"?

Comment: @vaxquis: Making the code longer makes it more readable, not less readable. What makes code more readable is *redundancy*, *length*, and *use of meaningful temporary variable names*. Brevity and dense expressions make code harder to read.

Comment: redundancy, length and using temporaries wherever possible... making code more readable... I think that either we're living on two opposite sides of a galaxy, or one of us is simply insane. btw, I see you're the guy who invented UnmodifiableSynchronizedReadonlyListViewPanel and the like...

Comment: @vaxquis: No, I assume that *if your loop is a performance impacting hot spot then your performance tests will show that*, at which time the sensible question to ask is not "how can I nano-optimize this loop?" but rather *how can I avoid doing this operation entirely?*  Don't waste your time making optimizations you're not going to need, and particularly don't waste your time making optimizations now that preclude larger optimizations later.

Comment: factoring out invariants weren't and won't be a nano-optimization for the reasons stated above. Reducing the complexity of the algorithm by a constant factor is *never* a nano-optimization. Have you ever programmed a microcontroller, Eric? If so, why are you hurting people with views like "we shouldn't optimize without profiler even at the concept level!"?

Comment: @vaxquis Truth be told, if you care about performance, I'm not sure why you'd eliminate temporary variables and yet compile with a zero-optimization switch or target a runtime with a non-optimizing JITter. Other than that, the readability issues you mention are obviously completely subjective and everyone can have their own opinion on that, since I know a lot of people (most people, in fact), who find long identifier names more readable (mainly because in large frameworks they have a chance of eliminating lookup time in the framework documentation).

Comment: Using temporary variable when the value is used only 1 time and the code is self-explanatory *is* an overkill, because there simply ain't any justification for it. As for the optimization, it was presented here because for some architectures (as I said already, uC come to mind) the compilers simply aren't too good at producing optimized code (was the case for most of uC C compilers for years and was the reason for using asm inlining there). As for the readability - exactly - it *is* subjective, that's exactly why I consider anybody saying *what makes the code more readable* a hand-waver.

Comment: nb, I said that "using a temporary" makes in less readable in *this particular case* - since, as I already pointed out, using temporary makes sense when either (or both) a) the operation is complicated/multistep by itself, b) the value will be reused in the future, or c) we simply *have* to create a temporary to store something for later use (e.g. var swap). I can't find any other rational justification for using a temporary var - and creating variables without justification certainly *makes the code worse*, otherwise it wouldn't generate *warnings in almost all compilers* (unused var/val).

Comment: That would be convincing if `condition` was forbidden to have side-effects, but without that, the restriction still seems arbitrary. Also, as another answer points out, `i += (c?d:e)` does work, which *stylistically* is equally bad.

Comment: @vaxquis: If the value of `n` can change mid-loop, I would suggest using something other than a `for` loop; if the value cannot change mid-loop, I would prefer to have a loop bound which is set once before the start of the loop and doesn't change.  My preferred rendering would probably be to use either use temporary values for `itemsLeft` and `stepSize` if `n` can't change mid-loop, or `do { ... if (i > n) { i--; if (i <= n) break;} else if (i < n) { i++; if (i >= n) break; } while(true);` if it can.

Answer (score 17):

replace

```
0 <= n ? (i++) : (i--)
```

with

```
i += ((0 <= n) ? 1 : -1)
```

that should work

Comment: +1. Ternary operators should usually return a value without altering its source (which is done with `i--` or `i++`).

Comment: While this is good advice, it doesn't really answer the question *why* this syntax (which works perfectly well e.g. in C and JavaScript) should be invalid in Java.

Comment: -1 for dumping code without explanation. "Do this and this and it will work" is not good advice to give for a learner/beginner. You're encouraging him/her to copy/paste code arbitrarily without actually understanding it.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is giving you an error mostly because you're trying to solve your problem with invalid algorithm. The fact that JLS doesn't allow ternary as a condition in [for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1) doesn't help either - but the main problem is that you miss the valid solution of the task at hand.

Let's start with a common statement, `prematureOptimization == sqrt(sum(evil))` - first you should consider *what* you want to do, not *how* to do it or *why* the code doesn't work.

- the loop should just execute n times, using i as a counter
- i step should be 1 if n is >= 0, otherwise -1

  (side note: if n is invariant (and it is here) using e.g. abs(n) or n < 0 in the condition is a bad practice; although most compiler will try to factor the invariant out of the loop, you should usually simply use a temporary var to store the result and use the result in the comparison instead)

So, the code at hand should be:

```
void doSomething( int n ) {
  if ( n >= 0 )
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
      f( i, n );
  else
    for( int i = 0; i > n; i-- )
      f( i, n );
}
```

Factoring out invariants and separating distinct code branches are basic techniques used to increase algorithms efficiency (not a *premature optimization*, mind me); there's no faster nor more clean way to do this. Some may argue this is a case of [loop unwinding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding) - it very well *would be*, if not for the fact that those two loops shouldn't be wound together in the first place...

Another thing: third op in **for** loop was always an ordinary statement; let's try to guess *why doesn't the following code compile?*

```
0 <= n ? (i++) : (i--); // error: not a statement
```

... maybe because following code won't compile either?

```
0 <= n ? i : i; // error: not a statement
```

... and that's for the very same reason code below won't work in Java either?

```
i; // error: not a statement
```

Your answer is: **ternary is not a statement - ternary just returns the value, and value is not a statement** (*at least in Java*); `i++` and `i--` are allowed in ternary just because they return a *value*, but they also produce *side effects* here.

Comment: +1 for extracting the two completely different cases into separate loops. this answer should be way up there with Eric's, as it's the cleanest way to solve the task at hand. It's maintainable and the optimizer can easily understand the structure of the loops, making it efficient without micro-optimizing